# Julia can't precompile Genie.jl

Tags: julia, genie.jl

I'm on Ubuntu and would like to use Genie.jl but I can't even get Genie to precompile.
It's also not the only error message I get. By just running "using Genie" gives me the following:

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: syntax: invalid keyword argument syntax "webserver"
```

I already tried `Pkg.resolve()` and `Pkg.instantiate()` and `pkg> update`. All without success.

Comment: I recommend you append a comment to [this issue](https://github.com/GenieFramework/Genie.jl/issues/496) and provide details for the package maintainers.

Comment: What Julia version? Is this with Genie 4 or Genie v 5? Genie.jl docs say that it requires only Genie v 5 with Julia 1.8?

Answer (score 1):

Noticed that Julia was on version 1.4.1. After updating all problems were resolved.